# Sphinx code block renders strangely in HTML

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to use Sphinx code blocks and I am getting strange rendering in HTML. My source is:

[The following image shows both the source code used and how it was rendered in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j19ZF.png)

Here is the source rst for the page

```
************
Testing Page
************

Used for testing Sphinx constructs

Why does the role get rendered in HTML?

..code-block:: python

    This is a code line
    and so is this.

It is very confused because it emits the following error::
   D:\Shared\WiseOldbird\Projects\Platform IndependentApplicationController\docs\source\Test.rst:12: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent

If I try it like this without the language specification it renders the role and displays the code block correctly -
note that it strips a single colon from the role directive

..code-block::

 This is a code line
 and so is this.

If I use a literal block.::

   I get a colon in the text that introduces the literal block

Heading
-------
```

What do I need to do to use Sphinx code blocks correctly?

Comment: Please show us code and markup as text, not as an image.

Comment: I have no idea how to show the markup as text on Stackoverflow

Comment: I am attempting to show the rendered HTML output.

Comment: Yes that's fine. But please provide RST markup as plain text.

Comment: A space is missing. Change `..code-block:: python` to `.. code-block:: python`.

Comment: If I do that I get a diagnostic from Sphinx complaining about the format. All the examples I have seen in Sphinx documentation omit the space.

Comment: The warning only appears for the code block without language specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A space is missing in the `code-block`.

  Change `..code-block:: python` to `.. code-block:: python`.
- A `code-block` directive must have an argument specifying the language.

  See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block.
- A space is also missing before the colons in the paragraph before the literal block.

  Change `literal block.::` to `literal block. ::` to remove the colon in the rendered text.

Comment: I will add that one empty line should be between the `.. code-block:: python` and the actual code (I had this bug and ended up here so I add my issue).